# Travis env variables returns empty

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, karma-runner, travis-ci

I want to use `environment variables`/`matrix` to test my repo in 2 different builds.

I have a gruntfile with 2 tasks and I would like to make a BUILD env variable like this:

```
  - grunt --verbose $BUILD:travis
```

where the `$BUILD` would be alternativly `nocompat` or `default`.
**What am I doing wrong?**

My .travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
- 0.11

env:
  - BUILD='nocompat'
  - BUILD='default'

before_script:
    - npm install grunt-cli -g
    - curl https://gist.github.com/santiycr/5139565/raw/sauce_connect_setup.sh | bash

script:
  - grunt --verbose $BUILD:travis
```

Comment: You have not told us what is going wrong. Is it not starting enough builds? Or is it not replacing $BUILD with 'nocompat'/'default'?

Could you possibly link to a travis build page where it isn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on irc conversation it looks like there are extra settings in the `.travis.yml` that are conflicting with this.

For example, given a `.travis.yml` that looks like this:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
- 0.11

env:
  matrix:
    - BUILD='nocompat'
    - BUILD='default'

env:
  global:
    - SAUCE_USERNAME=....
    - SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY=....

before_script:
    - npm install grunt-cli -g
    - curl https://gist.github.com/santiycr/5139565/raw/sauce_connect_setup.sh | bash

script:
  - grunt --verbose $BUILD:travis
```

You actually need:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
- 0.11

env:
  matrix:
    - BUILD='nocompat'
    - BUILD='default'

  global:
    - SAUCE_USERNAME=....
    - SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY=....

before_script:
    - npm install grunt-cli -g
    - curl https://gist.github.com/santiycr/5139565/raw/sauce_connect_setup.sh | bash

script:
  - grunt --verbose $BUILD:travis
```

If you imagine YAML as JS what you were doing before was this:

```
config = {};
config.env = {'matrix': ...};
config.env = {'global': ...};
```

The `global` setting was hiding the `matrix` setting.